# What type of curtains do I need to buy?

Tags: windows, bedroom

Our bedroom is pretty bright from the streetlights at night and the sun in the morning. This affects our sleep quality, so I am thinking of buying blackout curtains. I never bought curtains before and don't know at all which type to buy for the curtain pole in the bedroom. I read something about eyelit, pencil pleat, etc. but struggle to see which one is right. The curtain pole and the hooks on there look quite weird to me - I have attached two photos. We cannot take the pole out, so I assume we need to use these small hooks or get some larger hooks to be put around the pole. Since we rent this flat, I would like to use this pole and not replace it with something else. Could anyone tell me what type of curtain we need and what type of hooks we need to buy to fix it to this pole?

Many thanks!

[image: Curtain pole close]

[image: Curtain pole far]

Comment: Just a word of advise, in my experience, manufacturers are very "flexible" with the term blackout curtain. For example, I have 2 different brands of blackout curtains in 2 rooms, both of which I wouldn't consider full blackout anyway, but one style is almost just a lightly dimming kind, while the other one does make it quite dark. But both are really more of a grey-out. If you can, read online reviews of what you;re going to buy before purchasing.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: @DanielGriscom I don't think this falls into "shopping". He's not asking about which is best or where to buy, but what "class" or "category" of curtain to purchase.

Comment: @FreeMan Well, in the past "shopping" has been expressed pretty broadly. But, I'm only one vote; if nobody else votes to close then it won't be.

Comment: fair enough, @DanielGriscom. I thought it seemed pretty reasonable. We'll let the community decide (since that's how it works 'round here).

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this style rod with pleated curtains. There are dozens of tall metal hooks that slip into pockets in the top of the curtain, then the hook sticks out of the curtain and goes through one of those holes.

There should be cords on one side or the other that will allow you to open and close the curtains, similar to the pull cords for the blinds.

Apparently, they make hooks for this type of curtain rod that have pins that can go through a "regular" curtain to adapt it to this type of rod. [This happens to be the first thing I found in a search that looked correct](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CPKJMYH), so there's no particular endorsement of the vendor or the product, but it's an idea of what you're looking for in a hook. This means that you can buy pretty much any curtain and use these hooks.

[This appears to be the more "traditional" type hook](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Curtain-Hooks-Metal-Single-Prongs-Pinch-Pleat-Drapery-Hook-for-Drapes-Tapes-Silver-Tone-100-Pcs/404195496) that I was thinking of. You can use these if you find a curtain that is designed for these.

<s>Sorry, I don't know the exact "name" for this kind of curtain.</s>

Thanks to mattman944, I now know these are called "pinch pleat" curtains, and they hang on a "traverse rod". It's called a "traverse rod", I'd imagine, because when you pull the cord the curtains traverse across the rod. ;)

Comment: Pinch pleat on a traverse rod. The hook attaches below the top allowing the rod to be covered by the curtain. All our windows had these when I was a kid in the 1970s.

Comment: @Mattman944 thank you kind sir! That's where I know them from, too. Gentlemen of a certain age, eh? :)